# passing image to a matlab function

Tags: matlab

i have a function

```
function[a,b,c] = segmentimage(image)
```

i am not able to give the image **'bird.png'** to this function.

1. i get an error if i write

   ```
   segmentimage('bird.png')
   ```

   as

   ```
    Error: File: segmentimage.m Line 27 Column: 66
   ```
2. if i declare

   ```
    image= imread(bird.png)
   ```

   before the function declaration, then also i am getting an error

   ```
   Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts.
   ```

please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Option 2 is fine. If you saved the function properly, you should write after that just `segmentimage(image)`, without `function[a,b,c]= ...`

Comment: @user3012742 please post some of your code, especially line 27 where there is the error, so we can evaluate it and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In option 2 I think you're doing something like this in your script,

```
image= imread(bird.png)    
function[a,b,c] = segmentimage(image)
```

First of all, you should have

```
image = imread('bird.png');
```

and you should not declare anything in the function script, so, erase the first line.

it should be,

```
function[a,b,c] = segmentimage(image)

%your code here,

im = imread(image);
%a = ...
%b = ...
%c = ...

end
```

then you can call your function in another script,

```
[a, b, c] = segmentimage('bird.png');
```

About the first error, you have to post some code, especially the line in which the error occurs so we can help.